# python import ttk and * from tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new in `tkinter`.
I see video tutorials to learn it.
in this video he import from `tkinter` with this code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
```

i know first line means import all class, function and ... in `tkinter` and `ttk` must included.
why write second line when he import all with`*` that must included `ttk`.
and i try to write first line and remove second line but then i can't use code like this:

```
button = ttk.Button(text = "text")
```

and get error that `ttk` was not found.
what different when `ttk` import separate? and why `ttk` not included when we use `*` in first line.
thanks.

Comment: because not all classes etc.. are imported using the `*` syntax, whatever is specified in `__all__` will be what is imported

Comment: Please pick one site, don't cross-post http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/258084/110531

Comment: thanks.
and i remove http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/258084/110531

Comment: Adding a link for details on what @PadraicCunningham said: https://docs.python.org/3.0/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is pretty simple: `from tkinter import *` doesn't import ttk because that's how it was designed to work. Why did they design it that way? It doesn't really matter. When you create a module, you can define what gets exported and what doesn't, meaning you don't have to export everything. In this case the original developers chose not to export ttk.

In my opinion you should never do a global import (eg: `from tkinter import *`) because it makes your program less clear. I recommend you do this:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
...
b1 = tk.Button(...)
b2 = ttk.Button(...)
```

It becomes crystal clear which library you are using, at the expense of having to type three extra characters for every widget. Since code is read considerably more times than it is written, optimizing for readability is a smart thing to do.

For more information on how `import *` works, see the [python 3 tutorial on importing](https://docs.python.org/3.0/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package). Also see the [section on importing in PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports), which discourages wildcard imports. From that document:

> Wildcard imports (from  import *) should be avoided, as they
>   make it unclear which names are present in the namespace, confusing
>   both readers and many automated tools.

Answer (score -2):

From what I know, the first line must be enought, and I'm not recognizing the sintax of your second code.

For me, it may look like like this:

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
button = button(window, text="text")
button.pack()
```

I hope I have answered your question and otherwise, you can ask me and I will try to answer from what I know.

Comment: its work but not good.
ttk.Button != Butoon.
and ttk.Button is Beautiful than Butoon without ttk.

Comment: Ok, as you'd like these kind of things I can't answer that but I suggest you to read what @PadraicCunningham have said about this.

Comment: i read that and that good for me. i also read @user3885927 link and its useful too.